# Body not coming inside Lambda Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I have created a API on api gateway which uses lambda as Authorizer, This API accepts form data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). I have logged the whole event that is coming to lambda from API gateway, headers, query params are coming in the event but Body is missing, how do I retrieve the body in lambda. (event.body is empty)

Comment: This is traditionally generated in a HTML form POST.  How are you sending data in?